# regex match proc name without slash

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of proc names on Linux.  Some have slash, some don't. For example,

**kworker**/23:1

**migration**/39
**qmgr**

I need to extract just the proc name without the slash and the rest.  I tried a few different ways but still won't get it completely correct.  What's wrong with my regex?  Any help would be much appreciated.

```
>>> str='kworker/23:1'
>>> match=re.search(r'^(.+)\/*',str)
>>> match.group(1)
'kworker/23:1'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the regex is, that the greedy `.+` is going until the end, because everything after it is optional, meaning it is kept as short as possible (essentially empty). To fix this replace the `.` with anything but a `/`.

```
([^\/]+)\/?.*
```

works. You can test this regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/Z8Cixr/1). In case it is new to you, `[^\/]` matches anything, but a slash., as the `^` in the beginning inverts which characters are matched.

Alternatively, you can also use `split` as suggested by Moses Koledoye. `split` is often better for simple string manipulation, while regex enables you to perform very complex tasks with rather little code.

Comment: yup... I think this works.

    re.search(r'^(\w+)/?',str)

Comment: Works as well. Anything, that will not take the slash would work (e.g. [a-zA-Z0-9_]). `[^\/]` is just the most liberal approach, working with any character in the proc name (except a `/` of course)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to regex is to `split` on *slash* and take the first item:

```
>>> s ='kworker/23:1'
>>> s.split('/')[0]
'kworker'
```

This also works when the string does not contain a slash:

```
>>> s = 'qmgr'
>>> s.split('/')[0]
'qmgr'
```

But if you're going to stick to `re`, I think `re.sub` is what you want, as you won't need to fetch the *matching group*:

```
>>> import re
>>> s ='kworker/23:1'
>>> re.sub(r'/.*$', '', s)
'kworker'
```

On a side note, assignig the name `str` shadows the in built string type, which you don't want.

Comment: Yes; it's better to use `split` in that case. you could have explained that the regex doesn't work because `/*` should be `/.*` (`*` applies to the previous char)

Comment: but I may have a process name without /

Comment: @BillyK Both approaches will work even without a slash

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yes, but I thought they could for `re.sub` instead

Comment: Well. My head was stuck in digging the regex.  Didn't think about split it.  Yes, it is a quick fix.  Thanks a lot